# Draw piechart with highcharts using php array of data

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I want to replace PHP array `$os_array` with JavaScript variable to send with different values. Like as `var x =<?php echo $os_array; ?>; drawcharts($x);` when alert `var x` result will be `['Internet Explorer 7',1],['Internet Explorer 8',1],['Outlook 2007',2]`

```
var x="<?php echo $os_array;?>";
drawcharts(x);
function drawcharts(x){
    $('#_shared_graphs').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'OS'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{point.y} Using <b>{point.name}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Sent Messag stat',
                data: [x]
            }]
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is the title? Where is the question?

Comment: i want to replace php array $os_array with js variable  to send with differnt values .

like as 
var x =<?php echo $os_array; ?>;
drawcharts($x);

Answer (score 0):

well just define your js fkt:

```
function drawcharts(x) {

 $('#_shared_graphs').highcharts({
  ...

series: [{
        ...
        data: x
    }]
 });
}
```

then

```
 var x =<?php echo json_encode($os_array); ?>; 
 drawcharts(x);

 // reassign x
 x = [ .... ];
 drawcharts(x);
```

Comment: it not draw , my code like as above code  kindly check it

Comment: $os_array= ['Internet Explorer 7',1],['Internet Explorer 8',1],['Outlook 2007',2];

Comment: ok i have a solution :

    var x ="[<?php echo $os_array;?>]";
    x= eval(x);
    drawcharts(x);

Comment: edited with using json_encode to create a propper js-array output